# Add “Please fill out this field” string into Transifex

Tags: feature-request, localization, international-sites, transifex, time-travel-mode

> [image]

Comment: @Mari-LouA https://www.transifex.com. This system used for the translations for international sites.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you should clarify that in your question, I'm sure 95% users will be familiar with the term but not everyone on Meta is an engineer or computer programmer (me!).

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've used [tag:transifex] tag, thought that it would be enough =/